# update CSS variables in React dynamically?

Tags: css, reactjs

I searched a bit but didnt really find something that directly solved this.

If I have a var in CSS that is set to blue (--color:blue) and say I want to update it to red so that everything that relies on this varible is now changed to red, how would I approach that? For the sake of this discussion, lets assume its defined on the Body in css.
Im not supposed to access the document, which is my first thought coming from vanilla JS but I understand in react I should never do that.

Comment: You can't change CSS, you can make changes using Javascriptn React in your case, set a variable that will make call to your red color class, and that can be updated to use the class using the blue one ..

Comment: You wouldn't change the CSS variable. You would have two CSS variables and switch them out programmatically. Normally through classes.

Answer (score 2):

React is a UI framework, not an application framework.  So the simplest thing to do is to wire the ability to change the color *into* your UI framework by adding some code to your *application*.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
// Or use import { render } from 'react-dom'; if you're not on React 18

// Your _application_ logic can do things with the DOM directly
const changeThemeData = (newTheme) => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--color', newTheme.color);
};

const uiRoot = createRoot(document.getElementById("your-mount-point"));
uiRoot.render(
  <YourApp onThemeChange={changeThemeData} />
)
```

But if you want to avoid manipulating the DOM at all (because you want to manipulate the DOM for UI reasons and you want to keep all of your UI logic in your UI framework, for example), then the right thing to do is to move your styling from `body` to `yourMainElement`:

```css
/* Your CSS File.css */
#the-main-element {
  --color: red;
  /* etc. */
}
```

```js
function YourApp() {
  const styles = isMonday() ? {"--color": "blue"} : undefined;
  return <div id="the-main-element" style={styles}>Well, well, well</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Much appreciated! I dont personally mind manipulating the DOM persay, I just assumed that is frowned upon in React and generally not acceptable practice.